# How expensive are barriers if they don't need to synchronize?

Tags: vulkan

I have a barrier that synchronizes `host_write -> device_read` of a uniform buffer. This barrier is in *pre-recorded* command buffer, so basically it is executed every frame. But what if my uniform buffer not updated that often (say projection matrix)? Is it still ok to execute the barrier on static data that didn't change? How expensive it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specification has a special paragraph for situations when You write data directly to a memory (by mapping the memory), flush it and then submit a command buffer:

> The vkQueueSubmit command automatically guarantees that host writes
>   flushed to VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT are made available if they were
>   flushed before the command executed, so in most cases an explicit
>   memory barrier is not needed for this case. In the few circumstances
>   where a submit does not occur between the host write and the device
>   read access, writes can be made available by using an explicit memory
>   barrier.

This means that in Your case explicit memory barrier may not be necessary. But in situations when You write data to a memory only once, but reuse that memory multiple times, You could record a command buffer with a memory barrier and submit it only once. Then You can submit other command buffers, pre-recorded or not, multiple times and they don't need such barrier.

In general - barriers may introduce waiting so they may have a performance impact. So this means, if You don't need a barrier, You should avoid it.

Comment: "*barriers may introduce waiting*" A host source operation with a pure execution barrier can't introduce waiting, since there's no GPU operation to wait on. Now, a memory barrier tied to a `vlCmdWaitEvent` or a semaphore can introduce waiting. But it would be strange indeed for a pure barrier that uses the host as its source operation to cause this.

Comment: @NicolBolas I referred to a general barrier usage without diving into details as explained for example here: https://gpuopen.com/vulkan-barriers-explained/ In general, barriers may introduce waiting ("may" is the key here). They don't have to and, as You describe, host operation indeed may not introduce any waiting. But the general idea is that if we don't need a barrier (or any other operation) we should avoid it. But thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> How expensive it is?

As far as I can tell the specification gives **no** guarantees of barrier elision. So generally speaking, it may cost nothing, or it may cost the regular price (depending on driver).

Comment: Note that in traditional GL / D3D APIs, it's very, very common for applications (or drivers, on the application's behalf) to write data to uniform buffers that will then be read by the next (internal) command buffer submitted. So it's likely that hardware has made this particular case pretty cheap. Because of the automatic availability that Ekzuzy pointed out, all that needs to happen on the GPU is a visibility operation, which means invalidating the uniform cache hierarchy. I know some hardware has made that very efficient and well-pipelined because it's so common.